# Call Powershell Function with Parameter Object

Tags: powershell

Is is possible to create an object like so

```
    $Data = new-object PSObject
    $Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteName" -Value "Web Title"
    $Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteURL" -Value "https://www.test.url"
```

And then somehow call a function like

```
Do-CustomFunction $Data
```

Which would unpack the object and use its attributes as named parameters, to emulate the behavior of:

```
Do-CustomFunction -SiteName "Web Title" -SiteURL "https://www.test.url"
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You either declare two parameters for the function `Param( [string]$SiteName, [string]$SiteUrl)` or one object parameter `Param( [object]$SiteObject)` and inside the function work with the properties of that object: `$SiteObject.SiteName` and `$SiteObject.SiteUrl`. Using ParameterSets allows you to also have a combination of that. Also, you could consider using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) but you'll need to use a Hashtable for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `about_splatting`: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)

Example:

```
function mytest{
    param($path1,$path2)
    write-host $path1 $path2
}

$commands = @{
    path1 = "C:\temp\test.txt"
    path2 = "C:\temp\test2.txt"
}

mytest @commands
```

Notice referencing the hashtable with an `@` when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **SiteName** as **$SiteName** , you can do this with **Set-Variable**.

However, if you put this in function block, it does not set the variable properly for future use in the script execution.
After a lot of attempts, this is the best result i've reached, hope this is what you looking for.

```bsh
$Data = new-object PSObject
$Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteName" -Value "Web Title"
$Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteURL" -Value "httpss://www.test.url"


foreach ($att in $Data.psobject.Properties)
{
    Set-Variable -Name $att.Name -Value $att.Value
}

#CONSOLE:
$SiteName
#OUTPUT: Web Title
$SiteURL
#OUTPUT: https://www.test.url
```

Comment: My description was too vague apparently, apologies. By calling the function & unpacking I actually meant something else: question edited to reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mean like similar behavior of **kwargs in python ?

Comment: I forgot the name, exactly

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you could use ParameterSets to combine the option of either sending separate strings or an object containing the values:

```
function Do-CustomFunction {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByParams')]
        [string]$SiteName, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ParameterSetName = 'ByParams')]
        [string]$SiteUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'ByObject')]
        [object]$SiteObject
    )
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByObject') {
        $SiteName = $SiteObject.siteName
        $SiteUrl  = $SiteObject.siteUrl
    }

    Write-Host "SiteName: $SiteName  SiteUrl: $SiteUrl"
}
```

Using

```
Do-CustomFunction -SiteName 'SiteName' -SiteUrl 'SiteURL'
```

or

```
$Data = new-object PSObject
$Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteName" -Value "Web Title"
$Data | Add-member NoteProperty -Name "SiteURL" -Value "https://www.test.url"

Do-CustomFunction -SiteObject $Data
```

will both do nicely.