# PowerShell InputObject

Tags: powershell

All three of these methods display the results in similar manners. My question is why in METHOD 01, I can't use Write-Output {$_.FullName}, instead, I have to use a ForEach-Object?

I have to use METHOD 01 to run it against a function that I created.

```
Clear-Host

#METHOD 01
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0 | 
ForEach-Object{$_.FullName} | 
Sort-Object

#METHOD 02 (Sticking into Variable)
$AA = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0
Write-Output $AA.FullName | 
Sort-Object

#METHOD 03 (Sticking into Variable)
$AA = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0
ForEach($oItem in $AA)
{
    $oItem.FullName
}
```

Comment: You can use `Get-ChildItem | Write-Output -InputObject { $_.FullName }`, which resolves the ambiguity between pipeline input and argument.

Comment: Zett42, I know I can use $Input.FullName to call it from a function.  But how do I pass InputObject into my function?
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Directory -Depth 0 |
MyFunction -InputObject {-FirstName $_.FullName -LastName $_.FullName }

Comment: Simplest way is a filter function: `Filter MyFunction { $_ }`. This would be a "do nothing" filter. For more complex stuff create an [advanced function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) with a parameter that accepts pipeline input (`[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject`).

Comment: Thanks and I agree on the advance function Zett42. I found this and it is what I am looking for. I am going to analyze it. Thank You and have a good night.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434762/call-powershell-function-with-parameter-object

Comment: I didn't see your ValueFromPipeline earlier but when I did and found this site illustrate how to use it.  I think that is what I am looking for.  Thank You Zett42 https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/PowerShell/language/statement/function/parameters/attributes/parameter/valueFromPipeline/index#:~:text=Powershell%3A%20Param%20%28Parameter%20%28ValueFromPipeline%3D%E2%80%A6%29%20A%20parameter%20that%20has,to%20process%20the%20individual%20objects%20from%20the%20pipeline.